# How to retrieve PHP session in Perl file?

Tags: php, perl, session, cgi

I tried with CGI::Session and PHP::Session to retrieve PHP sessions in Perl but no luck still. Could you anyone help out me to resolve that task? using Core PHP for session.

```
use CGI::Session;
use PHP::Session;
my $session = PHP::Session->new($sid, { auto_save => 1 });
$session->set(foo => 'bar');
my $cgi = new CGI;
my $sid = $cgi->param("sid") || undef;
my $session = new CGI::Session::File($sid,
{
LockDirectory=>"/tmp/sessions",
Directory    => "/tmp/sessions"
});
# get the session id...
my $sid = $session->id();
print $session;
```

Also getting errors "Can't locate PHP/Session.pm in @INC (you may need to install the PHP::Session module)" but already installed by these cli perl -MCPAN -e shell +
install Session

Comment: Try run `cpan PHP::Session` and check if it is installed or not

Comment: @HåkonHægland Yes error gone for PHP::Session but still PHP session not retrieved in PERL. Have you any idea or script help to retrieve PHP session in Perl?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/PHP::Session#EXAMPLE and you're not looking at browser sent cookies.

Comment: @mpapec Tried with same code but still getting same. 
can't find session cookie sessionid have new mail in /var/spool/mail/--

Comment: how is this script being called?